# How do I change the style of a shape through the scope?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-google-maps

I am using a custom [GoogleMap AngularJS Directive](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps), the less popular version of GitHub.  I am using it because I was not happy with the way the [other](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps) one handled events.

I have a GeoJSON file full of shapes that fill a map.  I would to make it interactive so that you can select each area.  So I have managed to get the initial area select and area deselect to work but if you select an area then select a different one thereafter, it should change the style of the old selected area and update the new one.

I iterate over the GeoJSON file and make the scope.

```
$scope.shapes = [];
$http.get('/static/json/areas.json').then(function(res){
    for (var x = res.data.features.length -1; x >= 0; x--) {
        paths = [];
        for (var y = res.data.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0].length - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
            paths.push([ res.data.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0][y][3], res.data.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0][y][0]]);
        };
        $scope.shapes.push({
            areaName: res.data.features[x].properties.name,
            path: paths,
            fillColor: '#4F639E',
            fillOpacity: 0.4,
            strokeColor: '#4F639E',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight:1
        });
    };
});
```

Then use and ng-repeat to add them to the map.

```
<map
    zoom="13"
    center="[-33.955, 18.42]"
    disable-default-u-i="true"
    disable-double-click-zoom="true"
    draggable="true"
    keyboard-shortcuts="false"
    map-type-id="SATELLITE">
    <shape ng-repeat="shape in shapes track by $index"
        on-mouseover="areaOver()"
        on-mouseout="areaOut()"
        on-click="areaClick()"
        id="{{$index+1}}"
        name="polygon"
        stroke-color="{{shape.strokeColor}}"
        stroke-opacity="{{shape.strokeOpacity}}"
        stroke-weight="{{shape.strokeWeight}}"
        fill-color="{{shape.fillColor}}"
        fill-opacity="{{shape.fillOpacity}}"
        paths="{{shape.path}}">
    </shape>
</map>
```

Then I add the event listeners.
These two for the hover effects.

```
// Highlight area on hover
$scope.areaOver = function() {
    if ($scope.select != this.id) {
        this.setOptions({
            fillOpacity: 1
        });
    };
}

// Return area on mouse-out to previous style
$scope.areaOut = function() {
    if ($scope.select != this.id) {
        this.setOptions({
            fillOpacity: 0.4
        });
    };
}
```

This one for when an area has been selected

```
$scope.areaClick = function() {
    var path = this.getPath();

    // The first time area selected
    if ($scope.select == null) {
        $scope.select = this.id;
        $scope.map.fitBounds(get_bounds(path.j))

        this.setOptions({
            fillOpacity: 0,
            strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
            strokeWeight: 2,
            zIndex: +1
        });
    }

    // When the same area has been selected again - reset view.
    else if ($scope.select == this.id) {
        $scope.select = null;
        this.setOptions({
            fillOpacity: 0.4,
            strokeColor: '#4F639E',
            strokeWeight: 1,
            zIndex: -1
        });

        $scope.map.setZoom(13);
        $scope.map.setCenter({lat: -33.96, lng: 18.38});
    }

    // When a different area has been selected - reset old style then update new style.
    else {
        // Reset old selected shape
        $scope.map.data.revertStyle();  // Not working
        $scope.apply;

        for (var i = $scope.map.shapes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            $scope.map.shapes[i].setOptions({  // Not working
                fillOpacity: 0.4,
                strokeColor: '#4F639E',
                strokeWeight: 1,
                zIndex: -1
            });
        };
        $scope.apply;

        // Move / Style newly selected shape
        $scope.select = this.id;
        $scope.map.fitBounds(get_bounds(path.j))

        this.setOptions({
            fillOpacity: 0,
            strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
            strokeWeight: 2,
            zIndex: +1
        });
    };
}
```

Additionally a custom function to work out the center of the area selected.

```
// Custom Function
function get_bounds(path) {
    var smallest_lat = 360;
    var smallest_lng = 360;
    var largest_lat = -360;
    var largest_lng = -360;

    for (var i = path.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var lat = path[i].lat();
        var lng = path[i].lng();

        if (lat > largest_lat) {largest_lat = lat};
        if (lat < smallest_lat) {smallest_lat = lat};
        if (lng > largest_lng) {largest_lng = lng};
        if (lng < smallest_lng) {smallest_lng = lng};
    }

    var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(smallest_lat, smallest_lng);
    var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(largest_lat, largest_lng);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(northEast, southWest);

    return bounds;
}
```

How can I update the style of a shape from the scope? [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qemcB5Swv8LT1A9i4tsi?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.map.shapes[id]`

You are on the same page with me on  angular-ui google maps. :)

If this does not satisfy your question, please make a very simple plnkr based on the example,

https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/shape.html
or 
https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/shape_with_ng_repeat.html

Then, let me know. To create a plnkr, just simply click 'Plunkr' on the page.

I will make it fixed until you are satisfied.